# Debug error when trying to read from file and output altered string

Tags: c++

So I'm testing out a small program that reads a file containing a few lines of one or two characters each and, based on what characters are in the line, outputs directional arrows (Think DDR output style: "< ^ v >")

Just reading and outputting the lines as they appear in the text file works fine, but I can't edit the way they appear without getting a super generic debug error with no code or anything to tell me what the problem is. Is this just something I'm not allowed to do, or should I replace my string with an array?

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void output(string raw);

int main()
{
    string content_line;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("level1.txt", ios::out);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file, content_line))
        {
            output(content_line);
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}

void output(string raw)
{
    string row = "       ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= raw.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (raw.at(i))
        {
        case 'l': row.at(0) = '<';
            break;
        case 'u': row.at(2) = '^';
            break;
        case 'd': row.at(4) = 'v';
            break;
        case 'r': row.at(6) = '>';
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << row << '\n';
}
```

The text file as it appears right now is just:

```
u
d
l
r
ud
lr
ul
dr
```

Comment: `row` is empty.  If you wish to assign values to it, resize it first.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving now? There is a different constructor you could use for the string, but for what you're doing it likely makes no difference. `i < raw.size()`, not `<=`.

Comment: [I took a screenshot of the error itself (imgur link)](http://imgur.com/a/6jXUw), it appears every time the same way...

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I feel like an idiot for not catching that, thanks so much!!